# Why isn't my media query changing this element's background-color?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I created an ionic project and in the style.css file I want to use this syntax. The color stays light-gray even when I change the width to 1 or 0px.

```css
@media screen and (min-width 480px) {
    #color {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

#color {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, you took a screenshot of text rather than copying and pasting the text...? We need to see your markup for this in an MCVE in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width 480px) {
    #color {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}

#color {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (i.e. missing a colon between min-width and 480px).  Try this simplified version instead:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #color {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my syntax errors. I was typing too fast and didn't review it. You all were correct on my errors, but I found the solution to my problem though. In stead of putting the "@media" syntax in a css file, I simple put it in an html file using  the "style" element.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asyUU.png)

Answer (score -1):

Well try using ..

"lightgrey" ? There are two kinds of how you can write "grey". Have you tried to write lightgrey instead of lightgray?

It works for me.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant to say "lightgrey". This works on any web browser i use like chrome, firefox, and IE, but its not working in my app.